# How do I navigate from one activity to another in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Hi I am pretty new to flutter and software development in general. I can't seem to understand how do I navigate from one activity to another.
What I really want is when I press the login button it should navigate me to a new activity

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'button navigation',
    home: HomeActivity(),
  ));
}

class HomeActivity extends StatelessWidget{
  gotoSecondActivity(BuildContext context){

    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondActivity()),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home Screen'),
      ),

      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Go To Second Screen'),
          color: Colors.red,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          onPressed: () {
            gotoSecondActivity(context);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
class SecondActivity extends StatelessWidget {

  goBack(BuildContext context){

    Navigator.pop(context);

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Screen"),
      ),

      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            goBack(context);
          },
          color: Colors.green,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          child: Text('Go Back To Previous Screen'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the code for second activity which i want to navigate to:

```
class SecondActivity extends StatelessWidget {

  goBack(BuildContext context){

    Navigator.pop(context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Screen"),
      ),

      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            goBack(context);
          },
          color: Colors.green,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          child: Text('Go Back To Previous Screen'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How does onclick function works on flutter and how do I implement this on my button

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For you to understand the concept of navigation, think of a stack of papers stacked.

Every time you use:

`Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AnotherPage(),));`

you are "putting" a paper on that pile.

**push** is used to "put" a new paper in that pile.

**pop** is used to "pull" a paper out of that pile,in other words, you will go back to the previous paper(page)

Ex: `Navigator.pop(context);`

And there are other types of navigation, I suggest you see the documentation after, as @dm_tr said above.

Answer (score 4):

To navigate from one screen to another, you must use the `Navigator`. Here is an example to navigate on another page which class name is `AnotherPage` as you may see.

```
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AnotherPage(),));
```

But, while this may answer your question, consider learning flutter basics first before trying to make an App. [Here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics) is an example of a good explanation of Navigation

Answer (score 2):

You have to use navigator.

Create a class and put that inside:

```
Future push(BuildContext context, Widget page, {bool replace = false}) {

  if(replace) {
    return Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return page;
    }));
  }

  return Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return page;
  }));
}

bool pop<T extends Object>(BuildContext context, [ T result ]) {
  if(Navigator.canPop(context)) {
    Navigator.pop(context);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

After that you can navigate between the pages with this:

```
push(context, yourActivity());
pop(context);
```